# Multiple received callbacks in same App.cable.subscription

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm developing a chat function where I'd like to have several separate events within the same broadcasting channel for:

- Message has been delivered
- User is typing
- User has read message

Along with the regular flow of messages. I have gotten to the point where every single one of these events are correctly hitting the `received: (data) ->` callback, and displaying correctly to the correct user.

All events are submitted using different triggers on clientside, such as keydown, submit etc and processed differently, but they all in the end **hit the same received callback**. How can I scope out these events within this same `received(data) ->` callback to cover functionality as for when a user has stopped typing (but not sent the message?

**For instance, when user is typing:**

```
$(".new_im_message").on("focusin",function(e) {
  var values = $("#typing_user").val();
  App.instantmessage.is_typing(values);
});
```

Processed appropriately and then hits received callback:

```
  received: (data) ->
    $(".user_is_typing").show();
```

**User is no longer typing, and no message is sent**

```
$(".new_im_message").on("blur",function(e) {
  var values = $("#typing_user").val();
  App.instantmessage.is_blur(values);
});
```

Processed appropriately and then hits received:

```
  received: (data) ->
    $(".user_is_typing").show(); 
    $(".user_is_typing").hide(); <<<< can't hide and show at the same time..
```

How can I split the events up?

1. Is it possible to have multiple received callbacks within the same channel? `received1(data)` `received2(data)` etc.
2. **If not,** Can I condition it out depending on which data-type (is_typing) (is_blur) is hitting the received callback?
3. **If not,** Do I actually need to split it up into different channels entirely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you call `perform()` (i.e. when a user types) in your JS code, I suggest passing in the action; i.e. it might look like something like

```
@perform('typing')
```

then in your channel (ruby code), you need to have a method that will respond to the action above:

```
def subscribed
  stream_from 'someidentifier'
  # this line is optional. I just added this to immediately notify everyone in the chatroom that a new user joined in to the chatroom
  ActionCable.server.broadcast 'someidentifier', action: 'subscribed', user_id: current_user.id
end

# this will be called by the JS `@perform('typing')` above
def typing
  # we then broadcast to everyone in that chat room (a.k.a "someidentifier" chatroom), that a specific user is currently typing a message. Modify this as you wish
  ActionCable.server.broadcast 'someidentifier', action: 'typing', user_id: current_user.id
end

def blur
  ActionCable.server.broadcast 'someidentifer', action: 'blur', user_id: current_user.id
end
```

Then back in your `received(data)` function in your JS code, we will segregate the action into the appropriate response logic:

```
received: (data) ->
  switch data.action
    when 'subscribed'
      # do something when a new user (data.user_id) has joined in the chatroom
      console.log(data.user_id)
    when 'typing'
      # do something when a user (data.user_id) is typing 
      console.log(data.user_id)
    when 'blur' 
      # do something when a user (data.user_id) stopped typing
      console.log(data.user_id)
```

Comment: This is obviously the correct answer. Works like a charm.